# Mysql can't find column names when using joined sub-query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, inner-join

I am using the below code..

```
SELECT 
    a.auction_id,
    a.name,
    media.media_id
FROM 
    auctions AS a
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id=a.owner_id 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT media_url 
                FROM auction_media 
                ORDER BY media_id ASC 
                LIMIT 1) AS media ON a.auction_id=media.auction_id
WHERE 
        ............
```

However I am getting errors such as `Unknown column 'media.media_id' in 'field list'`
 or `Unknown column 'media.auction_id' in 'on clause'` - why is this?

I am sure I have used similar queries before without any problems like this.

**Edit:** Just tested my other query where I do something similar and I was using `*` as the field select. Seems I can't reference the joined sub-query table though.

Comment: media_url is the only column available to the super query from the subquery

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks, that fixed it. Feel free to post an answer.